# Trying to run a function in a game loop, and then exit that function and run a separate function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pygame

I'm creating a connect four game using pygame. I created a function called playerOne that contains all the code for that player's turn. I have a second function called playerTwo that contains all the code for the second player's turn. in my game loop, i want to call the first function, have that player make a move, and then have the second player make a move. This should cycle until the game is over. The issue is that its only running one function and never moving onto the next, no matter how much I try. In the following code, I cut out most of my functions code because its just repeating itself. Thank you in advanced to anyone who looks over this code!

```
import pygame as pg 

#window Size, Sprites, Colors, etc.
display = pg.display.set_mode((500, 500))
white = (255, 255 , 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
board = pg.image.load('board.png')
chipRed = pg.Rect(10, 10, 10, 10)
chipBlack = pg.Rect(10, 10, 10, 10)
display.fill(white)
display.blit(board, (100, 100)) # draws the blank board
playerOneOver = False # Defaults to having player one's turn be NOT over


#board in list form, so the game can later store were chips are located 
boardRowOne = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
boardRowTwo = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
boardRowThree = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
boardRowFour = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
boardRowFive = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
boardRowSix = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']

#Player ones move
def playerOne():
    #player settings
    chipColor = red

    #display player one is up
    pg.draw.rect(display, chipColor, (230, 5, 20, 20))

    #Colum selection
    mousePressed = pg.mouse.get_pressed()
    mousePos = pg.mouse.get_pos()   
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT: #Exit Out
            pg.quit()
            exit()
        if columOne.collidepoint(mousePos) and mousePressed[0]: # if colum one was selected
            if 'b' in boardRowSix[0]: # if nothing is in row 6 colum one
                del(boardRowSix[0])
                boardRowSix.insert(0, 'r')
                pg.draw.rect(display, chipColor, (110, 320, 20, 20))
                playerOneOver = True
            elif 'b' in boardRowFive[0]: # if nothing is in row 5 colum one
                del(boardRowFive[0])
                boardRowFive.insert(0, 'r')
                pg.draw.rect(display, chipColor, (110, 280, 20, 20))
                playerOneOver = True
            #The above elif is repated for every other colum and row, but I cut it out for my post

#player two move
def playerTwo():
    #player settings
    chipColor = black

    #display player one is up
    pg.draw.rect(display, chipColor, (230, 5, 20, 20))

    #Colum selection
    mousePressed = pg.mouse.get_pressed()
    mousePos = pg.mouse.get_pos()   
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT: #Exit Out
            pg.quit()
            exit()
        if columOne.collidepoint(mousePos) and mousePressed[0]: # if colum one was selected
            if 'b' in boardRowSix[0]: # if nothing is in row 6 colum one
                del(boardRowSix[0])
                boardRowSix.insert(0, 'B')
                pg.draw.rect(display, chipColor, (110, 320, 20, 20))
            elif 'b' in boardRowFive[0]: # if nothing is in row 5 colum one
                del(boardRowFive[0])
                boardRowFive.insert(0, 'B')
                pg.draw.rect(display, chipColor, (110, 280, 20, 20))
            #The above elif is repated for every other colum and row, but I cut it out for my post

#game loop
while True:

    #Draw the colum selection
    columOne = pg.Rect(105, 70, 30, 30)
    columTwo = pg.Rect(150, 70, 30, 30)
    columThree = pg.Rect(190, 70, 30, 30)
    columFour = pg.Rect(235, 70, 30, 30)
    columFive = pg.Rect(280, 70, 30, 30)
    columSix = pg.Rect(320, 70, 30, 30)
    columSeven = pg.Rect(365, 70, 30, 30)
    pg.draw.rect(display, blue, (105, 70, 30, 30))
    pg.draw.rect(display, blue, (150, 70, 30, 30))
    pg.draw.rect(display, blue, (190, 70, 30, 30))
    pg.draw.rect(display, blue, (235, 70, 30, 30))
    pg.draw.rect(display, blue, (280, 70, 30, 30))
    pg.draw.rect(display, blue, (320, 70, 30, 30))
    pg.draw.rect(display, blue, (365, 70, 30, 30))

    if playerOneOver == False: # only run if player ones move is over
        playerOne()
    if playerOneOver == True: # run when player ones move is over
        playerTwo() 
    pg.display.flip() # updates the drawings

    #print the board list
    print(boardRowOne)
    print(boardRowTwo)
    print(boardRowThree)
    print(boardRowFour)
    print(boardRowFive)
    print(boardRowSix)
```

Comment: playerOneOver is global variable. In your function playerOne(), playerTwo() should declare "global playerOneOver" to modify the variable's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try printing out `playerOneOver` in your while loop. You'll see that it's always `False`.

Its a problem of scope. You are trying to update the `playerOneOver` variable inside of the `playerOne()` function, but because of scope what is actually happening is that a new `playerOneOver` is being created in your function, its not updating the one you define at the start.

This is desired behavior. You can read lots and lots about scope, for example [here](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html).

A more pythonic way to update a variable would be by storing the return value of a function. Consider the code below to fix your problem.

```
a = 'woo'

def update_bad():
    a = 'wee'

def update_good():
    return 'wee'

print 'Before bad update:',a
update_bad()
print 'After bad update:',a

print 'Before good update:',a
a = update_good()
print 'After good update:',a
```

Comment: I wish there was a pythonic operator to tether an out of scope variable in a function like C++'s & operator.